# Javascript : use string to invoke function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, function

My question is quite simple. In Php you can call a function including a string in the name of your function. Example :

```
function setName(name){
    $this->name = name;
}

$string = 'Name';
$method = 'set'.$string;
if(method_exists($this, $method)
    $this->$method($_POST['name']);
```

So I wanted to know if there was something like this in Javascript... For now, I'm using a switch to check the body id and call the function. This is my code :

```
switch($('body').attr('id'))
{
    case 'index':
        app.index.init();
        break;
    case 'login':
        app.login.inint();
        break;
};

app.index = {
    init : function(){
        console.log('Hola Mundo');
    }
};
```

So I was wondering if I could make something like this :

```
var id = $('body').attr('id');
app.id.init();
```

thanks for your answers.

Comment: You could do that, app is an object and you can reference a property by a string held in a variable via app[myVar].  However it's less secure than using a switch with definite function names defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done. You don't have to check it in switch. As id attribute is a string value so you can check directly property existence using `objectInstance[prop]` way and if it exists then you can invoke it safely:

```
app.index = {
    init : function(){
        console.log('Hola Mundo');
    }
};
app.login = {
    init : function(){
        console.log('Hola Mundo');
    }
};
var appProp = $('body').attr('id'); /* or var id = $('body').id; */
if(app[appProp]){
   app[appProp].init();
}
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks you a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
app[id].init();
```

But consider that this might cause an error if the id of your body is not defined in the app object, as James already pointed out.